# tkinter: exiting for loop without getting _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm making a programm where pressing the "Start calculating" button starts a for loop where in the final version, something will be calculated. I want to display the current number of completed calculations as well as a progessbar.

This is the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
MAX = 30000

def calculation():
    for x in range(MAX):    #total amount of calculations to be made
        #do some calculations here that take a bit of time but not always the same
        label["text"]=x
        progress_var.set(x)
        window.update()


window = Tk()
window.geometry("662x438")
button=Button(window,text="Start calculating",command=calculation)
label = Label(window,text="Number of completed calculations")
progress_var = DoubleVar()
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(window, variable=progress_var, maximum=MAX)

button.pack()
label.pack()
progressbar.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

window.mainloop()
```

The program works but moving around the window pauses the for loop (I guess a problem of the window.update() command?). Also when closing the window, I get this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<module2>", line 20, in calculation
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1331, in __setitem__
    self.configure({key: value})
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1324, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1315, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".91207344"
```

I know this is because I close the window and the loop in line 20 still tries to change the label of the window that has been closed.

I saw some examples of using the window.after() method for continously counting up but I want to do some calculations in the for loop and the won't always take the same time.

So how could I implement that without causing an error when closing (and idealy without freezing the process when moving the window)?

Comment: "_I saw some examples of using the window.after() method for continously counting up but I want to do some calculations in the for loop and the won't always take the same time.

So how could I implement that without causing an error when closing (and idealy without freezing the process when moving the window)?_"    Do the calculations first and then call after.  Then, right before you close the window, call after_cancel http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the "freeze while moving the window"; as far as I can tell, it works well on OSX.

You can catch the error thrown when closing the app while the calculations are being made: import the low level `_tkinter` module, and catch the `_tkinter.TclError` error thrown.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import _tkinter   #<-- import the low level _tkinter module

MAX = 300

def _calculation():
    for x in range(MAX):    #total amount of calculations to be made
        #do some calculations here that take a bit of time but not always the same
        label["text"]=x
        progress_var.set(x)
        window.update()

def calculation():   #<-- catch the exception in a try/except block
    try:
        _calculation()
    except _tkinter.TclError:
        pass


window = Tk()
window.geometry("662x438")
button=Button(window,text="Start calculating",command=calculation)
label = Label(window,text="Number of completed calculations")
progress_var = DoubleVar()
progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(window, variable=progress_var, maximum=MAX)

button.pack()
label.pack()
progressbar.pack(fill=X, expand=1)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work fine. Is there a reason for including the try except block in a separate function "calculation" which then calls "_calculation" instead of directly including it in the "for x in range(MAX):" loop?

Comment: Yes, there is: Functionally, it does the same as your suggestion, but is arguably clearer. Separating the try/except block in this fashion puts the emphasis on the use of the low level `_tkinter ` module, which I think is important here.